# Windows Api Multi-threading Messages

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I'm just curious as to to how to implement multi-threading without using a Windows API WaitFor* function that stops the program until the thread has returned. What's the point of using threads if they stop the main application from being resized or moved etc.?

Is there any form of windows messaging with threading, which will allow me to call my thread function and then return, and handle the return values of the thread when it finishes running?

Comment: Call/return are not appropriate terms for inter-thread comms - threads cannot be called and cannot return.  Use appropriate inter-thread comms as provided by your OS and GUI implementations.  On Windows, that's going to be SendMessage() or, preferably, PostMessage().  Do not try to wait on GUI event-handlers - that's not how GUI threads are designed to work!

Answer (score 3):

If you want your UI thread to know when a task thread has finished it's task then you could have your task thread post a (custom - WM_USER and above) message to your main window (along with thread id plus the handle). And the window proc of the main window can know that a particular task thread has finished it's task. This way the UI thread does not have to wait actively (using WaitFor*) on the thread(s) object.

Comment: +1 - posting messages is the classic way of communcating to a GUI thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` to wait for the thread to finish and also process messages at the same time.

Comment: One point to note with MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx approach is that when new tasks threads have to be added, the wait has to be aborted and new array created with the newly added handles - and then the wait call should be re-issued. Also the total wait-able handles are limited to 64.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at std::thread, boost::thread, just::thread, for multithreading in general for c++.

But about Windows messaging win32 and MFC, the MSDN states **explicitely** that **it is not multithread, it is monothread**. ( Undefined behaviour is to be expected if multithreading is used)

For asynchronous message emited in other thread than the main application window thread, you should use ::PostMessage(), that will insert message events in the monothread message pump of the mono threaded window.

Comment: Again. +1 for PostMessage API.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the msgs guys - I've implemented a unique GUID Registered message for my threads. 

But I'm curious as to this concept of 'monothreading'. I assume in the above it means that the messaging always happens in a single thread which all windows have access to?

Comment: it's not that "all windows have access to" this thread, indeed all windows of a process are managed only by the main window/application thread. That is a link of guy asking what is the message pump http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b44f06fb-fc4a-4fac-87cd-48b2953ea5fa/ and this one is a presentation of the message queue system http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

[`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be non-blocking, just pass zero timeout as second parameter:

```
// Check is thread has been finished
if(::WaitForSingleObject(threadHandle, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
   // Process results
   ...
}
```

You will need to periodically check this condition, e.g. on timer or after processing any message in message loop.

Or you can use [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It will unblock and return when some message/input event occured in calling thread message queue.

As other answers mentioned there is another way - using Windows asynchronously posted message to signal that thread has done its work. This way has disadvantage - the working thread must know target window or thread to post message to. This dependency complicates design and raises issues about checking thread/window lifetime. To avoid it message broadcasting (`PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST,...)`)
can be used, but this is overkill for your case, I don't recommend it.